# Absorbtion of elements into Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question

When I think about Normal subgroups in Group Theory, I think of a group being partitioned by a special subgroup. The cosets formed from the subgroup themselves form a group.

I'm learning rings now, and they talk about an Ideal working like a Normal Subgroup. They proceed to introduce the following definition:

> A subring $A$ of a ring $R$ is called a (two-sided) ideal of $R$ if for
>   every $r \in R$ and every $a \in A$ both $ra$ and $ar$ are in $A$.

Then they talk about how an ideal $A$ can be understood as "absorbing" in the sense that for any $r \in R$, $rA = A$.

The analogy to normal subgroups then gets confused in my mind here then:  For an ideal, for a general $r$ we have $rA = A$. For a normal subgroup for a general $g$, $gH \neq H$.

How is the ideal acting like a normal subgroup then?

Comment: A left ideal $A$ of $R$ satisfies that for each $r\in R$, $rA\subset A$, **not** $rA=A$ necessarily. Perhaps some textbooks always assume that $R$ is unital (for example, S. Lang's *Algebra*), and then it is equivalent to $rA=A$, and the same applies to right ideals. I think the analogy to normal subgroups is mainly based on the quotient structures, as it is necessary that $A$ is a two-sided ideal for the factor group $R/A$ to be a ring, parallel to that it is necessay of $H$ to be normal for the quotient set $G/H$ to have a group structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quotient ring $R/A$ we take cosets in the **additive** subgroup. That is, elements of $R/A$ are cosets $r+A$ for $r \in R$. So the ideal $A$ is acting like a normal subgroup in the additive group $(R,+)$—because it *is* a normal subgroup in the additive group, because addition in rings is commutative.